# Android: Updating a Textview for an activity inside a thread

Tags: android

Working with two activities.  If I wanted to do something like checking internet connectivity and updating another activity with the result, how do I get the statusMessage to display on the 2nd activity layout in the Textview there when I'm inside a thread of the 1st activity... Right now, the text doesn't change on the 2nd activity's textview.  If I need to reference a property from the 2nd activity from the first launch one, how do I do that?

```
Second Activity: 

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CopyOfSplash extends Activity {
protected boolean _active = true;
protected int _splashTime = 15000;
TextView mainText;
String statusMessage;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);    
                NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();    
                if (netInfo.isConnected()) 
                {
                     statusMessage= "Connected to the internet!";
                }   
                else
                {
                    statusMessage = "User is probably in airplane mode!";           
                }




            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.nwp.Main")); 
               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
    public void run() {               
                        setContentView(R.layout.main);
                  mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
           mainText.setText(statusMessage);
            }        

             });

                stop();

            }
        }
    };

    splashTread.start();
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        _active = false;
    }
    return true;
}
}


First Activity:

public class Main extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


  }
}

Manifest File:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nwp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"   android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Splash"
              android:label="@string/app_name"   
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.nwp.Main" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.nwp.Main" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just move the `TextView` changing code inside your second activity's `onCreate` method? In order to call `findViewById()` you need your `TextView`'s parent layout set as a content view of the current showing activity, otherwise `findViewById()` will return null.

Comment: What I'd like to be able to do is perform an operation such as checking Internet availability while the splash is being shown and return the success or failure of that operation to the 2nd activity as a text string--and I'm not clear on how to set the textview in the 2nd activity based on something that happened in a thread in the first.

Comment: You can add a public static boolean variable connected to your splash activity and then simply check it from the second activity.